# While i am trying to build flutter App, I am getiing LINK1168 error when i am trying to run using windows

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-tasks, flutter-run

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open E:\c tuts\flutter_application_1\build\windows\runner\Debug\flutter_application_1.exe for writing [E:\c tuts\flutter_application_1\build\windows\runner\flutter_application_1.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...                                    35.1s
Exception: Build process failed.
```

I was trying to build in windows

Comment: Does `E:\c tuts\flutter_application_1\build\windows\runner\Debug\flutter_application_1.exe` already exist?  Is it writable?  Is `flutter_application_1.exe` perhaps already running?